# PHP convert functions to MongoDB

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

Im trying to convert some of my PHP functions to mongodb, but cant figure it out, could someone help me out?

PHP function applications:

```
  function applications($gangId) {
        $applications = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `gang_applications` where `status`='avaliable' and `gangid`='$gangId'");
        return ($applications ? $applications : false);
    }
```

my attempt on function applications:

```
    gangshema.methods.applications(thisid) {
        // some sort of callback?
        db.gang_applications.find({status:avaliable, gangid: thisid}, function(err, cursor) {

            if (cursor != 0) {
                console.log(cursor);
            }

        });
    }
```

PHP function application_done

```
 function application_done($applicationId) {
        $applications = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `gang_applications` where `id`='$applicationId'")->row();

        return ($applications->status == 'avaliable' ? false : true);
    }
```

my attempt on function application_done

```
    gangshema.methods.application_done(applicationid) {
        db.gang_applications.find({id:applicationid}, function(err,cursor) {
            //   return ($applications->status == 'avaliable' ? false : true);
        });
    }
```

but my main consern is a function called accept_applications. I have no clue on how to do this part, including calling other functions for their response.

```
    function accept_application($userid,$applicationId) {
            $box = 'failure';

            if (empty($applicationId)) {
                $message = "applicationId is empty";
            } elseif ($this->application_done($applicationId)) {
                $message = "Already registred!";

            } else {
                $application = $this->getApplication($applicationId);
$test = true;
                if(!($test)) {
                    $message = "false test";
                } else {
                    $this->db->query("UPDATE `gang_applications` SET `status`='accepted', `by`='$userid' where `id`='$applicationId'");
                    $this->gangs->add_member($application->userid,'gang','member',$application->gangid);
                    $message = "Accept!";
                }

            }
            return $message;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this at the beginning of the Node.js script:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
```

---

First snippet:

```
function applications($gangId) {
    $applications = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `gang_applications` where `status`='avaliable' and `gangid`='$gangId'");
    return ($applications ? $applications : false);
}
```

becomes:

```
var findApplications = function(db, gangId) {
   var cursor = db.collection('gang_application').find({
     "status": "available" 
     "gangId": gangId
   });
   var results = [];
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      if (err) console.log("Error: " + err);
      } else if (doc != null) {
         console.log("Null document.");
      } else {
         results.push(doc);
      }
   });
   return results;
};
```

---

Second snippet:

```
function application_done($applicationId) {
    $applications = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `gang_applications` where `id`='$applicationId'")->row();

    return ($applications->status == 'avaliable' ? false : true);
}
```

becomes:

```
function applications(gangId) {
  db.gang_application
}
var applicationsDone = function(db, applicationId) {
   var cursor = db.collection('gang_application').find({
     "id": applicationId
   });
   var results = [];
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
      } else if (doc != null) {
         console.log("Null document.");
      } else {
         results.push(doc.status);
      }
   });
   return results;
};
```

---

Call both as follows:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (!db) {
    console.log("Database did not connect.");
  }
  else {
    findApplications(db, "102"); // Replace "102" with gangId
    applicationsDone(db, "104"); // Replace "104" with applicationId
  }
});
```

---

**EDIT** per comments, here's how to include a callback:

```
// Note extra `callback` parameter
var applicationsDone = function(db, applicationId, callback) {
   var cursor = db.collection('gang_application').findOne({
     "id": applicationId
   });
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
      } else if (doc != null) {
         console.log("Null document.");
      } else {
         return (doc.status == "available");
      }
   });
};
```

To call:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (!db) {
    console.log("Database did not connect.");
  }
  else {
    var callback = function(doc) { console.log(doc.status); };
    applicationsDone(db, "104", callback);
  }
});
```

---

**EDIT** Third snippet:

```
function accept_application($userid, $applicationId) {
        $box = 'failure';

        if (empty($applicationId)) {
            $message = "applicationId is empty";
        } elseif ($this->application_done($applicationId)) {
            $message = "Already registred!";

        } else {
            $application = $this->getApplication($applicationId);
            $test = true;
            if(!($test)) {
                $message = "false test";
            } else {
                $this->db->query("UPDATE `gang_applications` SET `status`='accepted', `by`='$userid' where `id`='$applicationId'");
                $this->gangs->add_member($application->userid,'gang','member',$application->gangid);
                $message = "Accept!";
            }

        }
        return $message;
    }
```

becomes this. Note some changes to the functions above to get this to work, such as returning an array of documents from `applications`, and using `.findOne()` for `applicationDone()`:

```
function acceptApplication(userId, applicationId) {
  if (!applicationId) return "No application ID";
  if (applicationDone(db, applicationId)) return "Application already submitted.";

  // Left out `if (!$test)`
  db.gang_applications.update({
    "id": applicationId,
    "userId": userId
  }, {
    "status": "accepted"
  }, upsert: false);

  //                    $this->gangs->add_member($application->userid,'gang','member',$application->gangid);

  return "Accepted!";
}
```

Comment: what about returning the information to future use? ( what about the 3rd snippet? :) )

Comment: See the example `.each()` statements for how I've used properties from each `doc` object. You could also add an extra parameter to each function (e.g., `var applicationsDone = function(db, applicationId, callback) {`, then `cursor.each(doc) { callback(doc); }`. Then pass a function with one parameter representing the document (e.g., `var fn = function(doc) { console.log(doc.status); }`) as the last parameter, and do functionality on the document within that callback function.

Comment: can i chat with you?

Comment: i just want to ask some future questions, ( note that i already accepted your answer :) )@nick bull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120710/discussion-between-nick-bull-and-maria).

Comment: what happend @nick bull ?